# get the coordinates from a random position and use them

Tags: java, android, button, random, set

My code should work something like this:

you see one dark button (clickable, [start_time]) and one grey button (not clickable, [buttongame1]). the buttongame1 predict, where start_time will move next.
when you click start_time, start_time moves to x and y of buttongame1.
At the same time, buttongame1 set it's position randomly new. 
now when you click start_time, start_time moves to the new x and y of buttongame1.
At the same time, buttongame1 set it's position randomly new, and so on.

I've tried this, but the problem is, I can't get or use the x & y from the buttongame1

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    int x0;
    int y0;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int x3;
    int y3;
    int x4;
    int y4;
    int x5;
    int y5;
    int x6;
    int y6;
    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.over);


    Random r = new Random();
    RelativeLayout decorView = (RelativeLayout) buttongame1.getParent();

    int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();

    i++;

    if(v == gameover){
        i--;
        btncounter.setText("GAME OVER");
        start_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
        anim.setStartOffset(20);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        textview1.startAnimation(anim);
        Toast.makeText(this, "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();
    }

    if (i == 0 ) {
        btncounter.setText("0");
        buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
        buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getHeight()));
        int x0 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
        int y0 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
    }

    if (i == 1 ) {
        btncounter.setText("1");
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
        buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getHeight()));
        int x1 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
        int y1 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
        start_time.setX((x1));
        start_time.setY(y1);

// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well just get X and Y from buttongame1 before you change it.

```
     if (i == 1 ) {
            btncounter.setText("1");
             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int x1 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y1 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
             buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getHeight()));

            start_time.setX((x1));
            start_time.setY(y1);
   }
```

This code also:

```
   if (i == 0 ) {
            btncounter.setText("0");
            int x0 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y0 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
             buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getHeight()));

   }
```